# Multiple zlib in vaired open source libraries, linker error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a C++ project involving Lua, PhysFS and an xml parser. Each of them contains a zlib. In PhysFS and Lua it's zlib version 1.2.3 and in the parser it's 1.2.5. They are in the same VS2010 solution but in different pojects. Building each project works fine. However, VS2010 reports linker error saying _*adler32*, _*inflate*, etc are already defined, while building the final executable. Strange enough, when I work on two different computers, one is complaining multiple declaration in Lua & PhysFS, while the other complains about Lua & xml parser. Both with VS2010 Express.

I need a workaround to avoid such problems. Since they are well maintained open source libraries, I prefer not modifying their source code.

Will it work if I compile each of them into .dll and .lib? My understanding is, multiple zlib declaration will still be in different .lib files. Is that true?

Thanks.

Comment: This is just a guess, but if you're statically linking you'll keep having these problems regardless of how you divide the projects. If you dynamically link, the different zlib DLL versions are compatible (in terms of exposed functions) so it should work. Not sure, though.

Comment: If you're statically linking, you can probably do some preprocessor trickery to ensure the linker gets the right function for each. However, it's probably best to use separate DLLs and load them as needed to avoid that kind of hacking.

Comment: Thanks @gnobal. I made it work by dynamic linking. Just being curious, how does OS X and iOS handle such stuff? Is it like in linux, that you don't have to compile the dependencies by yourself but just installing packages? Thanks!

Comment: @user2945422 I honestly don't know. I'm not familiar with the Apple ecosystem. Glad to hear you worked it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is through dynamic linking, i.e., pre-built DLL and corresponding lib file. In the lib file only part of the symbols(declarations) are exposed to the project using this DLL. Since zlib symbols are hidden, it is fine to have multiple zlib copies.